# How can I add values to a chart that do not exist as 0 in google data studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have got 4 tables in BigQuery that keep statistics for messages in a Message Queue. The tables are : receivedMessages, processedMessages, skippedMessages and failedMessages. Each table has among other things a header.processingMetadata.approximateArrivalTimestamp which as you might have guessed it is a timestamp field.

My purpose is to create 4 charts for each one of this tables aggregating in this field as well as a 5th chart that displays the percentage of each message category each day in regards to the receivedMessages as well as the unknown status messages using the following formula :

> UNKNOWN_STATUS_MESSAGES  = TOTAL_RECEIVED_MESSAGES - (TOTAL_PROCESSED_MESSAGES + TOTAL_SKIPPED_MESSAGES + TOTAL_FAILED_MESSAGES)

However some days do not have skipped or failed messages, therefore there are no records in Big Query in these two tables. This results to these 2 graphics having dates missing and also not displaying correctly the UNKNOWN_STATUS_MESSAGES in the 5th graph.

I also used the following code as a metric in my graphs with no success (changing the variable name appropriately each time).

```html
CASE WHEN TOTAL_FAILED_MESSAGES IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TOTAL_FAILED_MESSAGES END
```

Is there a way to make google data studio to fill the dates with no data with 0s so I can display the charts correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know the `date` boundaries of your chart, you can fill those holes with zeros. For instance, if you want to generate your report for last 30 days:

```
with dates as (
   select 
      x as date 
   from 
      unnest(generate_date_array(date_sub(current_date(), interval 30 day), current_date())) as x
)

select 
 date, 
 received_messages, 
 processed_messages, 
 skipped_messages, 
 failed_messages, 
 received_messages - (processed_messages + skipped_messages + failed_messages) as unknown_messages from (
    select 
       d.date,
       coalesce(count(received.*), 0) as received_messages,
       coalesce(count(processed.*), 0) as processed_messages,
       coalesce(count(skipped.*), 0) as skipped_messages,
       coalesce(count(failed.*), 0) as failed_messages
    from dates d 
       left join dataset.receivedMessages received 
          on date(received.header.processingMetadata.approximateArrivalTimestamp) = d.date
       left join dataset.processedMessages processed
          on date(processed.header.processingMetadata.approximateArrivalTimestamp) = d.date
       left join dataset.skippedMessages skipped
          on date(skipped.header.processingMetadata.approximateArrivalTimestamp) = d.date
       left join dataset.failedMessages failed
          on date(failed.header.processingMetadata.approximateArrivalTimestamp) = d.date
    
    group by 1
)
order by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the query. It was almost what I wanted (the only issue is that where there was no message the result was 1 instead of 0 but that was easy to fix). Also I would like to point out that naming the select values is OBLIGATORY otherwise for some reason data studio will not be able to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1) I recommend doing a join in BigQuery with a date master table to return '0' for those date values.

2) Otherwise, in Data Studio, make sure there is a field X that has values for all dates. Then create a calculated field with formula `X - X + TOTAL_SKIPPED_MESSAGES` and `X - X + TOTAL_FAILED_MESSAGES`

Answer (score 0):

As I found out it is also possible to do it in non fixed date using date parameters. So the first part of khan's answer can be rewritten as:

```
WITH dates AS (
  select * 
  from unnest(generate_date_array(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_START_DATE), PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', @DS_END_DATE), interval 1 day)) as day
)
```